# Can I join SELECT statements directly without using a view?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Is it possible to do the following without a creating a view in between? I.e. by just joining these SELECTs directly?

```
CREATE VIEW temp_first AS SELECT MIN(DATE) AS mindate,id FROM mytable GROUP BY id
#
SELECT *, t.mindate FROM aggregate_analysis a
JOIN temp_first t
ON t.id = a.id 
WHERE (.... ) 
ORDER BY mindate DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to replace the view refernce in the select with a sub query/sub select.

Have a look at

- [Subqueries in the FROM Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/unnamed-views.html)
- [Subqueries in MySQL, Part 1](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html) see *Pretending to be a Table*

Something like

```
SELECT  *, 
        t.mindate 
FROM    aggregate_analysis a JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  MIN(DATE) AS mindate,
                    id 
            FROM    mytable 
            GROUP BY id
        ) as t  ON t.id = a.id  
WHERE   (.... )  
ORDER BY    mindate DESC
```

Comment: Thx, this works! Unfortunately it still has some disadvantage some of the solution i tried had as well: I cannot SELECT this into a table, e.g. CREATE TABLE xxx AS SELECT yourcode... does not work because of the duplicate id column. If  do not select the id in the subselect, the join does not work anymore.

Comment: Change the * to a.*, and you should have no duplicate columns. It is typically always better to specify the columns, rather than use a select *